# Circumvent the path length restriction

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt, ntfs

There is a shared network drive that is being used from multiple locations. Some of the files from the network drive could not be used. On trying to open them I was getting the error "the file name is too long". I noticed that when I map the network drive into a local drive using subst from the command prompt the file opens just fine. Which led me to believe there is some problem with the path. I then used a command in PowerShell to get a list of all such offending paths also I came across a bulk file renaming utility that would enable me to make the file names shorter to make the file accessible again. But still this is not an elegant solution simply because the number of files is just too many.

In case you are wondering why dont I ask everyone to map the network drive to the local drive, that wont work for 2 reasons.
1. We need to email links to individual files to a lot of different users so if we send the link with a local mapping that link would not work for other users.
2. Also, some of these users are high level management users they cannot be bothered with following the path on their locally mapped drive.

I came across this link, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath based on my limited knowledge my interpretation was that the permissible path length can be increased from 260 to 32000 roughly. If that is the case that will be best solution but I do not know how to get there. Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you and sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 2):

Try \\?\ at beginning of path e.g. \\?\c:\long\file\name\etc\etc.txt

\\?\unc\server\share\long\file\name\etc.txt

E.g. \\server\share\dir\file.ext => \\?\unc\server\share\dir\file.ext

Comment: Source https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath ? Sounds like OP should have read it already

Comment: Since this is a network drive it starts like this \\networkdrivepath.. following your suggestion which is mentioned in the article \\?\\networkdrivepath does not seem to work.